# How do I display hierarchical data in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am currently trying to display information about a student's grades in a hierarchical layout, kind of like this:

https://support.schoology.com/hc/article_attachments/360004928433/Screen_Shot_2018-05-09_at_10.07.41_AM.png

Ideally, I'd like to be able to expand/collapse data, but I first need to be able to display actual data. I am still a little new to Swift and SwiftUI so I am having a bit of trouble, and I keep getting the following error: "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions."

Could somebody please help me out?

Here is my code so far:

```
var courses: [Course] { *Sample Data* }

struct GradeCalculatorView: View {
     @State var course = courses[0]  //Course that is currently selected by the user
          var body: some View {
              VStack {
                    Text(course.name)
                    List(course.categories) { category in
                        VStack {
                            Text(category.name)
                            List(category.items) { item in
                                HStack {
                                    Text(item.name)
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text(String(item.scoredPoints) + " / " + String(item.totalPoints))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you have a mistake that is confusing the type-checker and leading to the “unable to type-check” error. Even a simple mistake like misspelling a property name can trigger this behavior in a large expression.

Factor out subviews to help find the real problem. I'd factor like this:

```
var courses: [Course] { *Sample Data* }

struct GradeCalculatorView: View {
     @State var course = courses[0]  //Course that is currently selected by the user
      var body: some View {
          VStack {
                Text(course.name)
                List(course.categories) { category in
                    CategoryView(category: category)
                }
           }
      }
}

struct CategoryView: some View {
    var category: GradeCategory

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(category.name)
            List(category.items) { item in
                GradeItemRow(item: item)
            }
        }

    }
}

struct GradeItemRow: View {
    var item: GradeItem

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(item.name)
            Spacer()
            Text(String(item.scoredPoints) + " / " + String(item.totalPoints))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In fact, before posting this picture, I tried implementing something similar by adding a View object as a member of the Course, Category, and Item structs. However, that led to a view that I did not expect, with unintended horizontal lines spaced evenly throughout the page. I suppose I could try this approach and see how it goes.